# What's the difference between a string and a symbol in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, symbols

What's the difference between a string and a symbol in Ruby and when should you use one over the other?

Comment: A very excellent external blog post: [13 Ways of Looking at a Ruby Symbol](http://www.randomhacks.net/2007/01/20/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-ruby-symbol/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use symbols as hash keys in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189416/why-use-symbols-as-hash-keys-in-ruby)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The main difference is that multiple symbols representing a single value are identical whereas this is not true with strings.  For example:

```
irb(main):007:0> :test.object_id
=> 83618
irb(main):008:0> :test.object_id
=> 83618
irb(main):009:0> :test.object_id
=> 83618
```

Those are three references to the symbol `:test`, which are all the same object.

```
irb(main):010:0> "test".object_id
=> -605770378
irb(main):011:0> "test".object_id
=> -605779298
irb(main):012:0> "test".object_id
=> -605784948
```

Those are three references to the string "test", but are all different objects.

This means that using symbols can potentially save a good bit of memory depending on the application.  It is also faster to compare symbols for equality since they are the same object, comparing identical strings is much slower since the string values need to be compared instead of just the object ids.

As far as when to use which, I usually use strings for almost everything except things like hash keys where I really want a unique identifier, not a string.

Comment: Although symbols are not cleaned up by the garbage collector and stick around until the end of the runtime instance. So if you declare a lot of symbols you might be wasting a lot of memory.

Comment: @Daemin: This is generally a non-issue unless you are dynamically creating symbols en-masse.  This is the cause of memory ballooning in some apps.  If you use hard-coded symbols in your code, you are relatively safe.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first sentence. When people say each snowflake is unique, it means each one is different. Every occurrence is different from the other. However in your symbol code example you show each occurrence to be exactly the same object. Would 'identical' not be a better word?

Comment: I know how to create a string `something = “test”`. How do I do that for a symbol? Can you add something to your answer?

Comment: @Honey - you can do ```something = :test```

Answer (score 18):

What are the differences between Symbols and Strings?

1. Symbols are immutable: Their value remains constant.
2. Multiple uses of the same symbol have the same object ID and are the same object compared to string which will be a different object with unique object ID, everytime.
3. You can't call any of the String methods like `split` on Symbols.

From [Understanding Differences Between Symbols & Strings in Ruby](http://www.gaurishsharma.com/2013/04/understanding-differences-between-symbols-strings-in-ruby.html)

If you know Chinese, you can also read [理解 Ruby Symbol](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/opensource/os-cn-rubysbl/).

Answer (score 9):

The statement:

```
foo = "bar"
```

creates a new object in memory. If we repeat the statement:

```
foo = "bar"
```

We create another object.

To understand it more clearly please try this code in IRB:

```
foo = "bar"
puts "string #{foo} with object id = #{foo.object_id}"
foo = "bar"
puts "string #{foo} with object id = #{foo.object_id}"
```

You will get output like:

```
string bar with object id = 70358547221180
string bar with object id = 70358548927060
```

which clearly shows there are two different object for the same string. Now if you use a symbol it will create **one object per symbol** so:

```
foo = :bar
puts "symbol #{foo} with object id = #{foo.object_id}"
foo = :bar
puts "symbol #{foo} with object id = #{foo.object_id}"
```

shows:

```
symbol bar with object id = 7523228
symbol bar with object id = 7523228
```

which means there is only one object for `:bar`.

Further, Symbols are **immutable** and you can't call any of the String methods like `upcase` or `split` on Symbols.

Comparing Symbols are faster than comparing Strings.  Symbols can be thought of as constant/immutable strings that form a unique set that are effectively converted to memory pointers on the heap. This means comparing two symbols is fast because you are just comparing two integers (memory pointers).

Strings are mutable so the memory pointer to their value on the heap can change after modification. This means comparison operations are slower because duplicates can exist that are semantically equivalent.

Use a symbol when you are sure that the value will remain constant, for example use symbols for hash keys.  Use a string when you want to change the value or want to use a string method on it.

Answer (score 5):

An additional difference between `String` and `Symbol` is that a `String` has a lot more methods on it for string manipulation, while a `Symbol` is a relatively lean object.

Check out the documentation for the [`String` class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html) and the [`Symbol` class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Symbol.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are two main differences between String and Symbol in Ruby.

1. String is mutable and Symbol is not:

   - Because the String is mutable, it can be change in somewhere and can lead to the result is not correct.
   - Symbol is immutable.
2. String is an Object so it needs memory allocation

   ```
   puts "abc".object_id # 70322858612020
   puts "abc".object_id # 70322846847380
   puts "abc".object_id # 70322846815460
   ```

   In the other hand, Symbol will return the same object:

   ```
   puts :abc.object_id # 1147868
   puts :abc.object_id # 1147868
   puts :abc.object_id # 1147868
   ```

So the String will take more time to use and to compare than Symbol.

Read "[The Difference Between Ruby Symbols and Strings](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings)" for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Case where symbol can be disaster. Lets say you have
`params.map(&:to_sym)` in your rails controller .
Now here if you are converting the data provided by the user to symbol due to some reason then it could be dangerous. If the data provided by the user is too large and as we know that symbol is not a garbage collector, you might end up exhausting your server's memory which can takedown your website.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that string can have value inside a variable whereas symbol not . For example:

```
x     =     "hello"
p x  =>     "hello"
p :x =>     :x
```

Answer (score -1):

A symbol is something you use to represent names and strings.  You would want to use a symbol when you may have need to use a string several times as this far easier and more productive.

And just found this via google, which may offer greater detail: [Here you go](http://glu.ttono.us/articles/2005/08/19/understanding-ruby-symbols)

Comment: When supplying a link, please summarize the important information from the page and supply an attribution. Links rot then break, resulting in information that isn't useful. "[How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)" will help explain.

Answer (score -1):

Symbols and strings are completely different [this post](http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/SymbolsAreNotImmutableStrings.red) has a little insight into the differences. As to when and where to use them, there is a pretty extensive post on this subject over on [has many :through](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/4/19/symbols-are-not-pretty-strings).

Answer (score -1):

symbol is immutable and string is mutable.

when we perform any operation on string then it create a new object and take memory. As we perform more and more operation on string means we are consuming more and more memory.

symbol is object that are immutable mean if we perform any operation then it performs changes in original object, It will not create any object, that's why it is more profitable.

for more info, you can [click here](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/)

Comment: The link is broken. Please read "[How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)".