# How do I add strings to a hash of a hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
a = ["Bob Green", "Don Brown", "Rich Freedom"]

a_hash = {"key_name" =>{"name" => "a_name", "a_thing" => 0}}

keys = a_hash.keys

for i in 0..a.length
  aCOG = a[i]
  aCOGkey = a[i].to_s.downcase.delete(' ')

  keys[i] = aCOGkey
  a_hash[keys[i]]["name"] = aCOG   #why does this line fail?
end
```

Comment: It is really hard to figure what are you trying to do here. Try explaining what was the intent and what failed, error message, etc. Also please see the [FAQ].

Answer (score 2):

Let's see:

```
keys[0] == aCOGkey == a[0] == "bobgreen"
```

Looks like that line fails because there's no key "bobgreen" in `a_hash`.

Comment: It would create a new entry though, no?

Comment: It's been a while since I used Ruby, and I can't test it right now, but I'm pretty sure trying to access `name` before `a_hash[keys[i]]` is created causes it to crash.

Answer (score 1):

Nested hash does not just create on its own. In another word, Ruby does not know the value to the key is a hash too.

You may use all methods above to specifically assign a hash, or you can use

```
a_hash = Hash.new { |h,k|  h[k] = {} }
```

This assumes all values in `a_hash` is a hash (nested hash). This method can set default value to a hash. You can also set `h[k] = {name:"",a_thing:0}` in your case.

So you only need to do like:

```
a = ["Bob Green", "Don Brown", "Rich Freedom"]    
a_hash = Hash.new { |h,k|  h[k] = {} }    
a.each{|n| a_hash[n.to_s.downcase.delete(' ')]["name"] = n}
```

Try not to use `for` in Ruby. Use enumerators instead.
Use symbols for hash keys.

Comment: "Use symbols for hash keys", when it makes sense. Dogmatically trying to use symbols for hash keys can be frustrating because sometimes the key is too complex to be a symbol.

Comment: When it makes sense? Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189416/why-use-symbols-as-hash-keys-in-ruby Also, it's never too complex to be a symbol if you know you can use a symbol in this way `:"this is a complex symbol"`

Comment: A hash key isn't necessarily a string. It can be any object. Try converting all the objects you can imagine into a symbol. They don't fit. So, while it's a good practice to use symbols for speed and memory, it's not always expedient and doesn't always lead to the most readable code, votes withstanding.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson. I think everyone knows that. That post explains really well of my point. EOC.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a new key value pair to a hash inside a hash can work like this:

```
outer_hash['inner_hash_key']['new_key_in_inner_hash'] = 'String I want to add'.
```