# Why does HAML code usually use Ruby symbols (:http_equiv, :content) instead of plain strings ("http_equiv", "content")?

Tags: ruby, haml

HAML code usually uses symbols, like this:

```
%meta{:http_equiv=>"Content-Type", :content=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}
```

But why isn't it like this, using strings instead?

```
%meta{"http_equiv"=>"Content-Type", "content"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}
```

Both work fine.

What real benefit do HAML programmers see in using symbols instead of strings? I don't get it. My guess is that HAML just parses the string from the symbol anyway, so what's the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure you are referring to here: `{:http_equiv=>"Content-Type", :content=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}` is a Hash.  Here are some very good answers to the question "Why does Ruby use symbols as keys in Hashes?"

[Why use symbols as hash keys in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189416/why-use-symbols-as-hash-keys-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

the structures you're referencing there are maps, and the ruby standard is to use symbols as keys rather than strings.