# Pull key value from an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I've got an array of hashes, like this:

```
[
   {"name"=>"Bob Jones", "id"=>"100005913544738"},
   {"name"=>"Jimmy Smith", "id"=>"100005934513815"},
   {"name"=>"Abe Lincoln", "id"=>"100005954493955"}
]
```

I ultimately just want those id's in an array, like this:

```
[ 100005913544738, 100005934513815, 100005954493955 ]
```

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a = [{"name"=>"Bob Jones", "id"=>"100005913544738"},
     {"name"=>"Jimmy Smith", "id"=>"100005934513815"},
     {"name"=>"Abe Lincoln", "id"=>"100005954493955"}]

a.map{|h| h['id'].to_i}
# => [100005913544738, 100005934513815, 100005954493955]
```

[Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) is a very handy method to be familiar with.

It also seems worth noting that if you have control over the generation of the original Array, it's more Ruby-like to use Symbols (e.g., `:name` and `:id`) rather than strings as Hash keys.  There are [many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189416/why-use-symbols-as-hash-keys-in-ruby) for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = [
   {"name"=>"Bob Jones", "id"=>"100005913544738"},
   {"name"=>"Jimmy Smith", "id"=>"100005934513815"},
   {"name"=>"Abe Lincoln", "id"=>"100005954493955"}
]

h.map{|i| i.fetch("id").to_i}
#=> [100005913544738, 100005934513815, 100005954493955]
```