# more conventional way to write this ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

this ruby code works, but is there a more conventional or simplified way to write it:

```
options['host'] = begin
  a == :jaxon ? 'jaxon-server16.jaxon.local' : 'doric-server5'
end
```

I just feel like the code is a smell but I cannot put my finger on it.

Thanks.

Comment: No, it is does not smell, just the taste is a bit exotic.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: I'd say, though, that this usage of `begin..end` is not very widespread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually symbols are used as hash keys because they [save memory and are a little faster for comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189416/why-use-symbols-as-hash-keys-in-ruby), and the `begin..end` block is not necessary. Thus it becomes:

```
options[:host] = (a == :jaxon ? 'jaxon-server16.jaxon.local' : 'doric-server5')
```

This is a relatively long while, in my head the following parses easier:

```
options[:host] = 'doric-server5'
options[:host] = 'jaxon-server16.jaxon.local' if a == :jaxon
```

An iteration on top of that, is that you have what appears to be semi-hardcoded values (`jaxon-server16.jaxon.local` and `doric-server5`). You should store these in constants or another data structure in order to have these gathered in one place. For instance, if `doric-server5` becomes `doric-server6` one day, you'll only have to change it in the top of a class or file somewhere. Furthermore, it makes the code easier to read since they now have more humane names of whatever they represent.

```
# somewhere else:
JAXON_SERVER = 'jaxon-server16.jaxon.local'
DORIC_SERVER = 'doric-server5'

options[:host] = DORIC_SERVER
options[:host] = JAXON_SERVER if a == :jaxon
```

Since we've dealt with the original motivation to make it two lines, we could go back to one, nice line:

```
options[:host] = (a == :jaxon ? JAXON_SERVER : DORIC_SERVER)
```

If you have a lot of these kinds of statements, you could make a `server` hash, where e.g. `server[:jaxon] = 'jaxon-server16.jaxon.local'`, but if you just have two, two string constants are fine.

In some cases it's nicer to have the default option (in this case `DORIC_SERVER`) appear wherever it would default to that value, instead of setting the host to the default value directly. `Hash#fetch` takes two arguments: a key, and a value to default to, if that key doesn't exist.

```
options[:host] = JAXON_SERVER if a == :jaxon

# somewhere else:
options.fetch(:host, DORIC_SERVER)
```

Without more information, it's hard to say which approach is the best in your case. :-)

Comment: I like this line - *Without more information, it's hard to say which approach is the best in your case.*. To get the best answer,OP should need to work more in theirs *question* making.

Comment: wow fantastic answer. especially like the use of fetch with a default.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `begin..end` here.

```
options['host'] = a == :jaxon ? 'jaxon-server16.jaxon.local' : 'doric-server5'
```

I'd probably put parentheses around right side. Not necessary, just for clarity.

```
options['host'] = (a == :jaxon ? 'jaxon-server16.jaxon.local' : 'doric-server5')
```

Comment: With all due respect, I found other worthy answers by Sergio to upvote, but I will neither upvote nor downvote this one, as the `begin ... end` block somehow appeals to me, the old fan of Pascal lanuage, better than the sequence `... = a == :jaxon ? ...` Parenthesis does clarify it, though `begin ... end` has still its magic to it.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: yeah, Pascal does that to people :)

Comment: People maintain that in spite of the gaping differences, there is a [deep connection between Pascal and Ruby syntax](http://www.bitwisemag.com/2/Delphi-For-Ruby-What-s-The), which might be the reason why I became comfortable with Ruby in the end.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way to write it

```
options['host'] = case a
when :jaxon
  'jaxon-server16.jaxon.local'
else
  'doric-server5'
end
```

It has a lot more lines but i like its readability. It also makes it easy to add more hosts:

```
options['host'] = case a
when :jaxon
  'jaxon-server16.jaxon.local'
when :staging
  'staging-server1'
else
  'doric-server5'
end
```

Comment: Ideally, settings like this should be external to the app. They shouldn't be in the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to surround it with something for readability, you can share a pair of parentheses with the `Hash#store` method.

```
options.store( "host",
  a == :jaxon ? "jaxon-server16.jaxon.local" : "doric-server5"
)
```