# How to understand this ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I read following ruby code:

```
def callbacks(procs)
  procs[:starting].call     # line 1
  puts "Still going"
  procs[:finishing].call    # line 2
end

callbacks(:starting => Proc.new { puts "Starting" },   # line 3
          :finishing => Proc.new { puts "Finishing" }) # line 4
```

I can guess what it dose. But I don't know what `:starting` and `:finishing` in line 1 & 2 mean, and what `:starting=>` in line 3 and `:finishing=>` in line 4 mean. It's even hard to find a keyword to google.

Could anybody explain line 1,2,3,4 to me? If you may refer some official doc, that will be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`procs` is a [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html), `procs[:starting]` refers to the value for key `:starting`, which is set by:

```
:starting => Proc.new { puts "Starting" }
```

The method call is equivalent to:

```
h = {}
h[:starting] = Proc.new { puts "Starting" }
h[:finishing] = Proc.new { puts "Finishing" }
callbacks(h)
```

Comment: Is <code>:string</code> equivalent to <code>"starting"</code>?

Comment: @EvanLi `:string` is symbol and `"starting"` is string.

Comment: Why use symbol as hash key rather than string?

Comment: @EvanLi symbols are preferred in this case, but you can use any object. However, they are not the same - if the method expects symbols, passing strings won't work.

Comment: @EvanLi Today also asked [**`What is the use of a hash key with “:”`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328503/what-is-the-use-of-a-hash-key-with)

Comment: @Babai Please bare my ugly question. I just started learning Ruby a few days ago.

Comment: @EvanLi no problem..I started with much more uglier than you..so np..go on.. :)

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know what :starting and :finishing in line 1 & 2 mean

`:starting` and `:finishing` are the hash keys of the hash `procs`.

> what :starting=> in line 3 and :finishing=> in line 4 mean.

You are sending a Hash object as an argument via the method `callbacks`.

Read here [**`Hash`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html).