# Get value from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this hash.

```
[#<PartnerSite id: 20, site_name: "test123", user_id: 178, 
               market_id: 164, created_at: "2014-01-15 18:02:01", 
               updated_at: "2014-01-15 18:02:01", 
               ip_address_range: "50.19.93.173", 
               public_key: "453df9eeeb4a2d85bb7ffeb85486d489">]
```

And I am trying to access value by using

```
partner_site[public_key]
partner_site.public_key
```

But it's showing error like

1. `undefined local variable or method 'public_key'`  And
2. `` undefined method `public_key' ``  Respectively.

Comment: Wait, what query is giving you `undefined method 'site_name'`? Don't you mean `undefined method 'public_key'`?

Comment: Isnt that an activerecord object?

Comment: @Ajedi32- Sorry ..... I mean 'public_key'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, that looks like an array containing one `PartnerSite` object, not a hash. So you'll want to either get the first object in the array with `first`, (E.g. `partner_site = partner_site.first`) or loop through all the elements in the array with `each` and do something to all of them.

Secondly, when using the `[]` form for accessing values you usually need to provide either a symbol or a string to the `[]` method. In `partner_site[public_key]`, `public_key` references an undefined variable. Instead, you should do `partner_site[:public_key]` or `partner_site["public_key"]`.

Your other form, `partner_site.public_key` doesn't work because either you're calling `public_key` on the Array and not the `PartnerSite` object (in which case see the first paragraph in this answer), or because `PartnerSite` doesn't have a `#public_key` method defined on it. In the second case, you can probably fix that by adding `attr_accessor :public_key` to the `PartnerSite` class.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling to a variable that does't exist (public_key). Use a [symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Symbol.html) instead:

```
partner_site[:public_key]
```

If you want to find out why symbols are used as hash keys, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189416/why-use-symbols-as-hash-keys-in-ruby)