# Assignment inside a case statement

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do an assignment inside a when-then statement, but it doesn't work as I expected. As I see it, the problem is because, maybe, the case or when-then have a different scope than function. So, how I can reference my variable `message_header` to write the correct assignment? Or is other stuff?

```
  def message_notice(type, notice)
    message_header = ""
    case 'type'
      when 'danger' then message_header = 'Oops, something wrong happened'
      when 'success' then message_header = 'Done'
      when 'warning' then message_header = 'Hey, be careful'
      when 'info' then message_header = 'News, news'
    end
    return "<strong>#{message_header}!</strong> #{notice}"
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case 'type'
```

needs to be

```
case type
```

You're providing a constant string `'type'` to your case, not the variable `type`. None of your `when` 's will ever be matched, because none of them equal the string `'type'`.

You could also clean this up quite a bit by removing all identical assignments from each branch. Everything evaluates to a value in Ruby, so you the case statement will return the value from whichever branch is selected.

```
def message_notice(type, notice)
  message_header = case type
                   when 'danger' then 'Oops, something wrong happened'
                   when 'success' then 'Done'
                   when 'warning' then 'Hey, be careful'
                   when 'info' then 'News, news'
                   end
  "<strong>#{message_header}!</strong> #{notice}"
end
```

You might even want to take it a step further and simply store the type/message as a simple mapping:

```
def message_notice(type, notice)
  messages = {
    'danger' => 'Oops, something wrong happened',
    'success' => 'Done',
    'warning' => 'Hey, be careful',
    'info' => 'News, news'
  }

  "<strong>#{messages[type]}!</strong> #{notice}"
end
```

Comment: Some great suggestions here, though defining that hash inside the method repeatedly is a bit wasteful. It would be better as a module-level constant.

Comment: teh, re meagar's suggestion of using a hash, consider using symbols rather than strings for the keys (e.g, `:danger` rather than `'danger'`).  The reasons are several, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189416/why-use-symbols-as-hash-keys-in-ruby).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '  ' surrounding the type in the case statement.
You are checking if one of your 'danger','success',... strings is equal to 'type'. And thats never the case