# Display values using puts

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a Ruby program to deal two cards to one player. Here is my code:

```
def get_card (card)
  suit = (card - 1)/13
  if (card == 0)
    type = " of clubs"
  elsif (card == 1)
    type = " of diamonds"
  elsif (card == 2)
    type = " of hearts"
  elsif (card == 3)
    type = " of spades"
  end

  (card) % 13
  if (card == 1)
    return "ace" + type
  elsif (card == 11)
    return "jack" + type
  elsif (card == 0)
    return "king" + type
  elsif (card == 2)
    return "2" + type
  elsif (card == 3)
    return "3" + type
  elsif (card == 4)
    return "4" + type
  elsif (card == 5)
    return "5" + type
  elsif (card == 6)
    return "6" + type
  elsif (card == 7)
    return "7" + type
  elsif (card == 8)
    return "8" + type
  elsif (card == 9)
    return "9" + type
  elsif (card == 10)
    return "10" + type                      
  elsif (card == 12)
    return "queen" + type
  end
end

def deal_cards
  total_cards = (1..52).to_a.shuffle

  player_value = [total_cards.pop, total_cards.pop]

  puts "Your cards are " + get_card(player_value[0]).to_s + " and " + get_card(player_value[1]).to_s
end

deal_cards();
```

The part:

```
puts "Your cards are " + get_card(player_value[0]).to_s + " and " + get_card(player_value[1]).to_s
```

does not show the value of

```
get_card(player_value[0]).to_s
```

or

```
get_card(player_value[1]).to_s
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Question why don't you use return "10 #{type}#` instead of `+return`

Comment: Look at the first answer. Your code is to repetitive and, therefore, inefficient.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `(card) % 13` doesn't mutate `card`. What you probably wanted was:

```
card %= 13
```

---

However, note that your abstraction is a little confusing and you have a lot of repetition. Why not try something like this:

```
suits  = [:clubs, :diamonds, :hearts, :spades]
values = [*2..10, :jack, :queen, :king, :ace]

deck = suits.product(values).shuffle.map do |suite, value|
  {suite: suite, value: value}
end

player_cards = deck.pop(2)

puts "Your cards are #{player_cards.first[:value]} of #{player_cards.first[:suite]} and #{player_cards.last[:value]} of #{player_cards.last[:suite]}"
  # => Your cards are jack of spades and 7 of clubs
```

Comment: Not a big deal, but I don't see the reason of using symbols in `suits` and `values`. Isn't it more straightforward to use strings?

Comment: Here's why symbols:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189416/why-use-symbols-as-hash-keys-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def get_card (card)
  type = case ((card-1)/13)
  when 0 then "of clubs"
  when 1 then "of diamonds"
  when 2 then "of hearts"
  when 3 then "of spades"
  end
  card = case (card%13)
  when 0 then "king #{type}"
  when 1 then "ace #{type}"                 
  when 11 then "jack #{type}"
  when 12 then "queen #{type}"
  else card%13
  end
  "#{card} #{type}"
end

def deal_cards
  total_cards = (1..52).to_a.shuffle
  player_value = [total_cards.pop, total_cards.pop]
  puts "Your cards are #{get_card(player_value[0]).to_s} and #{get_card(player_value[1]).to_s}"
end

deal_cards()
```