# Rails 4 hash accessing values returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I seem to be stuck trying to access hash values coming from a csv file and could use a different pair of eyes to point out the obvious mistake I'm making.  Here is the relevant code:

```
  CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: :all) do |row|
  data = row.to_hash
  id = data['studentid'] # (have also tried id = data[':studentid'] but there are no :'s in the csv file headers, and double quotes instead of single)
  title = data['title'] # also (title = data[:title'])
     logger.debug "data param: #{data.inspect}"
     logger.debug "data title param: #{title.inspect}"
     logger.debug "data studentid param: #{id.inspect}"
```

From the log file:  (valid data x'ed out or fake - note studentid comes in as a fixnum)

```
data param: {:lastname=>"XXXX", :firstname=>"XXXXX", :title=>"XXXXXXX", :studentid=>123456, :date=>"XXXXXXXXXX"}
data title param: nil
data studentid param: nil
```

Rails 4.x Ruby 2.x OS Ubuntu
Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those keys are symbols. Try

```
id    = data[:studentid] 
title = data[:title]
```

Note: not `data[':studentid']`. `':studentid'` is simply a string that starts with a `:`

Comment: Thanks Ursus it's working now.  I knew it would be something simple.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

[Symbols](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html) and [Strings](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) are two basic object types in ruby. [They are different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255078/1954610).

The following hash:

```
{:lastname=>"XXXX", :firstname=>"XXXXX", ...}
```

is using **symbols** as keys, not strings. In order to access the values, you must also use symbol:

```
lastname = data[:lastname]
```

Again, to reiterate: `:lastname` and `':lastname'` are **not** the same thing; the former is a *symbol*, and the latter is a *string* (that starts with a `:`).