# Ruby get values from nested json response by using the json gem

Tags: json, ruby

I have a json response like this:

```
@response = {"result":{"amount":0.0}}
```

How can I get the value of amount into a variable?

I've tried:

```
@response['result']['amount']
@response['result'][0] 
@response[0][0]
```

I'm using the json gem.

Comment: I get syntax error with this `@response = {"result":{"amount":0.0}}`

Comment: You can indeed use bracket notation `[]` to access values from a json response. Just check all the available keys that can be passed into `[]` by calling `@response.keys`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@response[:result][:amount]
```

the keys in `@response` object are `:symbols` not `strings`

For more info: [What's the difference between a string and a symbol in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255078/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-symbol-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

With nested Hashes Ruby's [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method is very handy since it is returning nil if any intermediate step is nil.

```
@response.dig(:result, :amount)
```

If you are not sure is the key string or symbol you can use  [ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess) that provides `Hash#with_indifferent_access` (Rails will include this by default). Then you can get the value with both symbol and string formatted key.