# How to print Hash data in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am learning hashes and haven't figured out why it won't print the last line (`capital_city`).

```rb
more_states = {
  "Oklahoma": "OK",
  "Texas": "TX",
  "Colorado": "CO",
  "Kansas": "KS",
  "New Mexico": "NM"
}

puts "-" * 10
# Printing states and their abbreviations
more_states.each do |state, abbrev|
  puts "The abbreviation for #{state} is #{abbrev}"
end

more_cities = {
  "OK": "Oklahoma City",
  "TX": "Austin",
  "CO": "Denver",
  "KS": "Topeka",
  "NM": "Santa Fe"
}

puts "-" * 10
# Printing state abbreviations and the corresponding state capitals
more_cities.each do |abbrev, capital|
  puts "#{capital} is the capital of #{abbrev}"
end

puts "-" * 10
# Printing states, their abbreviations, and their capitals
more_states.each do |state, abbrev|
  capital_city = more_cities[abbrev]
  puts "The abbreviation for #{state} is #{abbrev}, and its capital is #{capital_city}"
end
```

My first two `puts` are working fine,  but when I use  `puts` within  `more_states.each`, I'm unable to access `more_cities`.

I tried using `more_cities.fetch` also:

```rb
capital_city = more_cities.fetch(abbrev)
```

With this, I got an error that it can't find the key "OK" in `more_cities`, but that key is definitely in there.

Any suggestions?  I feel like it's a syntax error, or I'm missing something.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your keys are symbols but you're using strings. Try making the hashes with `=>` instead of `:` or use `more_cities[abbrev.to_sym]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Key Type ([String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html) v [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html))

The key in the `more_cities` is a symbol (e.g., `:OK`); however, in `more_states` the `abbrev` is a literal string (e.g., `'OK'`). One solution is to convert the string to a symbol via the `String.to_sym` method.

---

### Code Update

*Notice the second line `abbrev` to `abbrev.to_sym`*

```rb
more_states.each do |state, abbrev|
  capital_city = more_cities[abbrev.to_sym]  # <-- here
  puts "The abbreviation for #{state} is #{abbrev}, and its capital is #{capital_city}"
end
```

---

### Supplemental

For more reading refer to these resources to describe a String v Symbol:

- http://www.gaurishsharma.com/2013/04/understanding-differences-between-symbols-strings-in-ruby.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/255099/10408280