# How to check if an element exists and append string

Tags: ruby

I have few items in `my_list`:

```
@my_list = {
  "all": [
    "prd02",
    "stg01",
    "prd01",
    "stg02"
    ],
  "prd": [
    "prd02",
    "prd01"
    ],      
  "stg": [
    "stg02",
    "stg01"
    ] 
}
```

Currently, I print all of them in `all`:

```
if @my_list['all'].include?(@item)
puts "#{@item}"
```

My current output is:

```
 prd02
 stg01
 prd01
 stg02
```

How can I check if that item is present in `"prd"` before printing the items? It should append "(prod)" and if that item is in `"stg"` it should append "(staging)".

I want to get my desired output as:

```
prd02 (prod)
stg01 (staging)
prd01 (prod)
stg02 (staging)
```

How can I check if the item is present in prd or stg?

```
if @my_list['all'].exists ? @my_list['prod'](@item)
puts "#{@item}.(prod)"
```

Comment: Note that there is no difference between `{"x": 1}` and `{x: 1}` except that the first form has a lot of useless extra characters. Unless you have spaces in your keys, just use the `x:` form.

Comment: Is the order of the found elements significant? In other words, do they have to be in the order they're found in `:all`? If not, the code can be very simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```rb
my_list = {
  "all": [
    "prd02",
    "stg01",
    "prd01",
    "stg02"
    ],
  "prd": [
    "prd02",
    "prd01"
    ],
  "stg": [
    "stg02",
    "stg01"
    ]
}

my_list[:all].each do |item|
  if my_list[:prd].include?(item)
    puts "#{item} (prod)"
  elsif my_list[:stg].include?(item)
    puts "#{item} (staging)"
  end
end
```

Please also note:

1. You have a syntax error in my_list declaration (missing `,`)
2. You need to use `:all`, `:prd` and `:stg` as symbols

See "[What's the difference between a string and a symbol in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255078/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-symbol-in-ruby)".

Answer (score 2):

```
labels = { :prd=>"prod", :stg=>"staging" }

@my_list.each { |k,v| (@my_list[:all] & v).each { |item|
  puts "#{item} (#{labels[k]})" } unless k == :all }
  # prd02 (prod)
  # prd01 (prod)
  # stg01 (staging)
  # stg02 (staging)
```

As

```
@my_list[:all]
  #=> ["prd02", "stg01", "prd01", "stg02"]
```

when

```
k = :prd
v = ["prd02", "prd01"]
```

we compute

```
@my_list[:all] & v
  #=> ["prd02", "stg01", "prd01", "stg02"] & ["prd02", "prd01"]
  #=> ["prd02", "prd01"]
```

See [Array#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-26).

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on learning Ruby. Since you are learning, I suggest an approach that illustrates how elegantly readable Ruby can be. This is neither the shortest nor the most verbose.

```
@my_list = {
  "all": [
    "prd02",
    "stg01",
    "prd01",
    "stg02"
    ],
  "prod": [
    "prd02",
    "prd01"
    ],      
  "staging": [
    "stg02",
    "stg01"
    ] 
}

collections = [:prod, :staging]

@my_list[:all].each do |item|
  output = item

  collections.each do |collection|
    output << " (#{collection.to_s})" if @my_list[collection].include?(item)
  end

  puts output
end
```

I would favor a naming convention that is a little more meaningful in your data structure by using "prod" and "staging" to match the variable names in *collections* and the outputted text.

This also allows you to quickly add additional collections by adding the corresponding symbol to the *collections* array.